# how to delete a selected label from multiple labels in an application using tapGesture (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms, label, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a button that creates a label each time it's clicked, let's say I clicked it 10 times, so now I have 10 labels created. How do I delete a random label the one I tap on?

```
PS: my labels are added to a stackLayout
```

The idea of my application is to create a todo list. I have an entry box and a button. I type what I want to do in the entry box, then click on the button and a label is created with which I just typed in the entry. When I'm done with something i want to tap on a specific label and remove it, how is that possible. Any help?

Code:

```
var entry = new Entry();
entry.Placeholder = "type here";
entry.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
entry.PlaceholderColor = Color.Gray;
var newButton = new Button { Text = "+", BackgroundColor = Color.Purple, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Button)), };
StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
stackLayout.Children.Add(entry);
stackLayout.Children.Add(newButton);
this.Content = stackLayout;

var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += labelClick;
newButton.Clicked += (sender, args) => { label = new Label();
label.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
label.TextColor = Color.Black;
label.Text = entry.Text;
entry.Text = "";
stackLayout.Children.Add(label);
label.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

Comment: please, could you add some code example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: var entry = new Entry();
            entry.Placeholder = "type here";
            entry.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            entry.PlaceholderColor = Color.Gray;
            var newButton = new Button
            {
                Text = "+",
                BackgroundColor = Color.Purple,
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Button)),
            };

            StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
            stackLayout.Children.Add(entry);
            stackLayout.Children.Add(newButton);
            this.Content = stackLayout;

Comment: var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += labelClick;

            newButton.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
            {

                label = new Label();
                label.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
                label.TextColor = Color.Black;
                label.Text = entry.Text;
                entry.Text = "";
                stackLayout.Children.Add(label);
                label.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
            };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have no idea how your code is and this makes a little hard to answer your question, but here's an idea:

If you are using a MVVM approach (which I recommend), you could create a View with this label, bind it to a ViewModel with the todo Item data (Id, Name, Details, ...), add the TapGesture and take action inside the ViewModel.

Edit:

Not the best way to do it or the way I would do it. But here is a solution based on your source:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        var entry = new Entry();
        entry.Placeholder = "type here";
        entry.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        entry.PlaceholderColor = Color.Gray;
        var newButton = new Button { Text = "+", BackgroundColor = Color.Purple, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Button)), };
        StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
        stackLayout.Children.Add(entry);
        stackLayout.Children.Add(newButton);
        this.Content = stackLayout;

        newButton.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var label = new Label();
            label.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            label.TextColor = Color.Black;
            label.Text = entry.Text;
            entry.Text = "";
            stackLayout.Children.Add(label);

            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (sensder, e) => DeleteLabel(stackLayout, label);

            label.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
        };
    }

    void DeleteLabel(StackLayout stackLayout, Label label)
    {
        stackLayout.Children.Remove(label);
    }
```

Comment: var entry = new Entry();

            entry.Placeholder = "type here";

            entry.BackgroundColor = Color.White;

            entry.PlaceholderColor = Color.Gray;


            var newButton = new Button
            {
                Text = "+",
                BackgroundColor = Color.Purple,
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Button)),
            };

Comment: StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
            stackLayout.Children.Add(frame1);
            stackLayout.Children.Add(entry);
            stackLayout.Children.Add(newButton);
            this.Content = stackLayout;

Comment: var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += labelClick;

Comment: newButton.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
            {

                label = new Label();
                label.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
                label.TextColor = Color.Black;
                label.Text = entry.Text;
                entry.Text = "";
                stackLayout.Children.Add(label);
                label.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
            };
        }

Comment: @Rémy take a look at the solution I proposed.